# Type Mismatch When Manipulating Subject Line of An Email (Lotusscript)

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I am running a Lotusscript Agent on "Before mail arrives". I need it to grab the text in the subject line after the "#" symbol. No matter how I try to get the Subject field (Evaluate, getFirstItem, getItemValue, etc), I always end up with an error. Usually it is a type mismatch or object variable not set.

The code below is my current code and returns an error 13 on line 14 "type mismatch"

```
Option Public
Option Declare

Sub Initialize
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler 
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim view As NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim nextdoc As NotesDocument
    Dim result As String
    Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
    Set view = db.Unprocesseddocuments
    If Not view Is Nothing Then
        Set doc = view.Getfirstdocument()
        While Not doc Is Nothing
            result = Evaluate ("@Right(Subject;""#"")", doc)
            Print result
            Set nextDoc = view.GetNextDocument(doc)
            Call doc.Remove(True)
            Set doc = nextDoc
        Wend
    End If
    Print "End"
Done: 
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler: 
    Select Case Err 
        Case Else 
            Print "Error " & CStr(Err) & " in agent on line " & CStr(Erl) & ": " & Error 
            Resume Done 
    End Select 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before New Mail Arrives does not return NotesDocumentCollection.
Use...

```
Sub Initialize
    Dim Session As New NotesSession
    Dim Doc As NotesDocument
    Dim result As String
    Set Doc = Session.DocumentContext
    Let result = StrRight(Doc.Subject(0), "#")
End Sub
```

instead of UnprocessedDocuments...

Comment: [14A0:0012-0F74] 03/09/2012 10:19:46 AM  Router: Agent printing: Error 13 in agent on line 15: Type mismatch

Comment: It depends, what you have on line 15 now. Try to add some Prints to a console.

Comment: The problem lies with "result = Evaluate ("@Right(Subject;""#"")", doc)" Whenever I try to get the Subject field, I always get an object not set or Type mismatch. But when i check the document properties, the subject field is there and contains text.

Comment: Ok, I modified the example. This is the most simple way to achieve your needs.

Comment: You, sir, are a champion. Thank you.

Comment: FYI: the reason you got the 'type mismatch' is because Evaluate returns an array of strings.  You had "Print Result" instead of "Print Result(0)"

Comment: Don't use Before New Mail Arrives when your agent is going to run for a long time. It might disrupt the Router process.

Answer (score 3):

With reference to your original question about the `Type Mismatch` when using Evaluate, please note the Designer help, under "Using the Evaluate statement":

> "*returnValue* is an array in which the type and number of elements
>   reflect the formula result; a scalar value is returned to element 0 of
>   the array. You should use a variant for the return value, since you
>   may not know how many elements are being returned."

Therefore, try the following changes:

```
    ...
    Dim result As Variant
    ...
    result = Evaluate (|@Right(Subject;"#")|, doc)
    ' Treat result as an array
    Print result(0)
    ...
```

Comment: Plus of course using StrRight is more practical than using Evaluate plus formula